# Image upload - Return URL

Tags: php, file-upload

Hello I build a script that does image uploading and resizing and it all works well, but how can I get the URL from image afterwards? I don't want my Image Source in HTML be like "../img/cat/1.png/" I want it to be like "http://MyIP/img/cat/1.png" I understand that I can just make a variable like $myHost = "http://blabla.com"; and add strip the ".." at the beginning but then it's not so good if I want to use it on other site because I need to replace this all the time. Maybe there is any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use some kind of solution like what you yourself have mentioned. You can use also:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

But it is not 100% reliable because of very different PHP configurations that can occur on different hosting services, and such.

Put your $myHost variable's content into a configuration file that you load up whenever you start your application. If you need to deploy the application on another server and domain and etc, just change the configuration. This is the most common way to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I think that you should explore the content of  $_SERVER array (e.g. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).